# What is the most efficient way to translate a string value domain enumerator?

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I have a public entity contract to expos in my service but internally I have some differences. In this specific case I have a string value domain represented as an enumerator. The domain is the same in both public and internal scope, but the names used are different and I need to translate from one to another. First I thought to keep to the basics and use a simple switch, but then I thought using a mirror enumerator with the internal string values I need and then use it with a `ToString()`. Wich one is the most efficient way to do this stuff?

## Enumerator

```
public enum PublicDomain {
    AAA = 0,
    BBB = 1,
    CCC = 2,
    DDD = 3
}

private enum InternalDomain {
    W = 0,
    X = 1,
    Y = 2,
    Z = 3
}
```

## Keep to the basics

```
string stringValue = null;

switch (publicEnumValue)
{
    case PublicDomain.AAA:
        stringValue = "W";
        break;
    case PublicDomain.BBB:
        stringValue = "X";
        break;
    case PublicDomain.CCC:
        stringValue = "Y";
        break;
    case PublicDomain.DDD:
        stringValue = "Z";
        break;
}

foo(stringValue);
```

## Enumerator > Enumerator > ToString()

```
private enum InternalDomain {
    W = 0,
    X = 1,
    Y = 2,
    Z = 3
}

foo(((InternalDomain)publicEnumValue).ToString());
```

Comment: How about a simple `Dictionary<PublicDomain, InternalDomain>`? Should be pretty efficient. Don't know why you use strings.

Comment: have you tried this, ((InternalDomain)((int)publicEnumValue)).ToString(); Please try this should work ...

Comment: This shouldn't be a question. Can't you just check what works faster with performance analysis (Alt + F2) or with help of Stopwatch class and simple work bench ?

Comment: Do you even have a _measurable_ performance issue here? Either way you posted (and came up in the comments) are _pretty fast_. Are you making hundreds of thousands of these conversions frequently?

Comment: The string value will be used on a COM+ call, witch is waiting a string. This question isn't an issue, I just thought in this two solutions and didn't found any data about that.

Answer (score 0):

I would not be concerned with "efficiency" but with maintainability.

I would have an extension to convert public `enum` to internal `enum`

```
static class PublicDomainExtensions
{
   public InternalDomain ToInternal(this PublicDomain e)
   {
      return (InternalDomain) e;
   }
 }
```

This way if `InternalDomain` or `PublicDomain` ever change, all you need to do is rewrite `ToInternal`.